# How to find duplicate data

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing a SQL query, where my goal is to find the duplicate values based on the column names:

```
SELECT a.PROJECTNAME 
 , a.OBJECTTYPE 
 , a.OBJECTID1 
 , a.OBJECTVALUE1 
 , a.OBJECTID2 
 , a.OBJECTVALUE2 
 , a.OBJECTID3 
 , a.OBJECTVALUE3 
 , a.OBJECTID4 
 , a.OBJECTVALUE4 
  FROM PSPROJECTITEM a 
 WHERE a.projectname  = 'AZ_HCM_745' 
 AND 1 < ( 
 SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM PSPROJECTITEM c 
 WHERE a.objecttype = c.objecttype 
   AND a.objectid1 =c.objectid1 
   AND a.objectvalue1 = c.objectvalue1 
   AND a.objectid2 = c.objectid2 
   AND a.objectvalue2 = c.objectvalue2 
   AND a.objectid3 = c.objectid3 
   AND a.objectvalue3 = c.objectvalue3 
   AND a.objectid4 = c.objectid4 
   AND a.objectvalue4 = c.objectvalue4) 
  ORDER BY a.projectname
```

My intention is to find those values, which are duplicate of `a.projectname`, I mean, the output should display the duplicate value of `AZ_HCM_745`, means, it should have same fields like `objecttype`, `objectid` and even the count of the object.

The output I am looking for this like this:

```
PROJECTNAME OBJECTTYPE  OBJECTID1   OBJECTVALUE1    OBJECTID2 OBJECTVALUE2  OBJECTID3   OBJECTVALUE3    OBJECTID4   OBJECTVALUE4
```

These are the fields name which I am selecting from the query.

Now i am passing a.projectname = 'AZ_HCM_745'.

My goal is to find the data which are duplicate of AZ_HCM_745 and the projectname which have these values, for eg:

```
AZ_HCM_745  0   1   AUDIT_AZ_ADP11P 0       0       0
```

is the original value.

The duplicated value is:

```
AZ_HCM_745_BKP  0   1   AUDIT_AZ_ADP11P 0       0       0
```

Please note that projectname can vary,_bkp or _a, my goal is to find the projectnames which have duplicate values of the objecttype, objectid1, and i want to select these value.

Also, the query must fetch only the duplicate values of the project name which is being passed in the parameter, not the projectname, means the original value must not be displayed, only the duplicates must be displayed

Database in use is Oracle.

Comment: If you provide example with input data and desired output it is much easier to understand what you want.

Comment: And what's wrong with the query? It looks alright.

Comment: Hi igor, it is not fetching the values properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem with your query is that it is "inside-out".  That is, you are only selecting the project of interest in the outer query.  The inner is selecting all the similar ones, but they are not being output because they are in a `where` clause.

Try this variation:

```
SELECT a.PROJECTNAME 
 , a.OBJECTTYPE 
 , a.OBJECTID1 
 , a.OBJECTVALUE1 
 , a.OBJECTID2 
 , a.OBJECTVALUE2 
 , a.OBJECTID3 
 , a.OBJECTVALUE3 
 , a.OBJECTID4 
 , a.OBJECTVALUE4 
  FROM PSPROJECTITEM a 
 WHERE a.projectname <> 'AZ_HCM_745' and
       exists ( 
 SELECT *
  FROM PSPROJECTITEM c 
 WHERE c.projectname  = 'AZ_HCM_745' and
       a.objecttype = c.objecttype 
   AND a.objectid1 =c.objectid1 
   AND a.objectvalue1 = c.objectvalue1 
   AND a.objectid2 = c.objectid2 
   AND a.objectvalue2 = c.objectvalue2 
   AND a.objectid3 = c.objectid3 
   AND a.objectvalue3 = c.objectvalue3 
   AND a.objectid4 = c.objectid4 
   AND a.objectvalue4 = c.objectvalue4) 
  ORDER BY a.projectname
```

A secondary consideration is that `NULL` values will not match (you'll need to use something like `coalesce()` if this is an issue).

Comment: thanks, also, i don't want to display the values of the projectname 'AZ_HCM_745' in the output, only the duplicate of this, means, which holds the data similar to this, though projectname, could be differ, must get displayed. I will try this.

Comment: Hi gordon, This is not displaying the output which i want. Little bit of modification, I will explain the output data, i have modified the query already. 'AZ_HCM_745''s duplicate data, means, objecttype,objectid, etc which is stored in the table, and projecname, which could be az_hcm_745_bkp' or some other name, that's what i am looking for. Even the data of az_hcm_745 must not get displayed. And there are more than one rows. thanks, this is very urgent

Comment: @vamosrafa . . . then just add another clause to the outer `where` clause.  Also, I had the wrong alias in the subquery for the project name.  It is fixed now.

Comment: Hi gordon, another thing, i want to know that is it possible to match the count of objects to mark them as duplicate? Thanks for the help.

Comment: There is another thing in this query, even the count of the objects must be matching to be labelled as an exact duplicate. Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, your objective is to  use project name to find the duplicated value in PSPROJECTITEM.

```
SELECT t2.objecttype
,t2.objectid1
,t2.objectvalue1
,t2.objectid2
,t2.objectvalue2
,t2.objectid3
,t2.objectvalue3
,t2.objectid4
,t2.objectvalue4
FROM PSPROJECTITEM t2, PROJECTNAME t1
WHERE t2.objecttype = t1.objecttype
AND t2.objectid1 = t1.objectid1
AND t2.objectvalue1 = t1.objectvalue1
AND t2.objectid2 = t1.objectid2
AND t2.objectvalue2 = t1.objectvalue2
AND t2.objectid3 =t1.objectid3
AND t2.objectvalue3 = t1.objectvalue3
AND t2.objectid4 = t1.objectid4
AND t2.objectvalue4 = t1.objectvalue4
AND t1.projectname   = 'AZ_HCM_745'
```

if there are unique ID in your database, please use it

Comment: Appreciate your understanding, my goal is to fetch the data of the projectname, which i am passing in the where clause. This is just for testing purpose, i will be writing an application engine program in peoplesoft, where the parameters will be passed dynamically. My intention is to find the duplicate data of the projectname which i have passed, ie, the objectid,objectvalue1, etc are same, and to find the projectnames which have these data. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT a.PROJECTNAME,
count(a.PROJECTNAME) as count
FROM PSPROJECTITEM a 
GROUP BY a.PROJECTNAME HAVING count(a.PROJECTNAME) >1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but, i don't want to diplay the PROJECT NAME which i am passing in the where clause, i want the duplicate values of the fields, like objectid, objecttype, i.e in the output :)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :

```
  SELECT A.PROJECTNAME,A.objectid, A.objecttype ,COUNT(*) DUBLICATE FROM PSPROJECTITEM A GROUP BY A.PROJECTNAME,A.objectid, A.objecttype HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```